# Need help fixing functions concerning URL detection (window.location.href.indexOf)

Tags: javascript

I've currently written some functions in Javascript detecting on which page I am and changing a class in my page (in order to keep an html tab open).

Some functions (the majority) work very well in order to detect page URLs but a few are not functionning correctly.

```
$( document ).ready(
    function() {


// Services

if (window.location.href.indexOf('?action=services') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Services").className = "dropdown open";
    }

else if (window.location.href.indexOf('cart.php') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Services").className = "dropdown open";
    }

else if (window.location.href.indexOf('cart.php?gid=addons') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Services").className = "dropdown open";
    }


// Domains

else if (window.location.href.indexOf('clientarea.php?action=domains') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Domains").className = "dropdown open";
    }


else if (window.location.href.indexOf('/cart/domain/renew') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Domains").className = "dropdown open";
    }


// Not working


else if (window.location.href.indexOf('/cart.php?a=add&amp;domain=register') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Domains").className = "dropdown open";
    }


else if (window.location.href.indexOf('/cart.php?a=add&domain=transfer') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Domains").className = "dropdown open";
    }


// Factures 

else if (window.location.href.indexOf('clientarea.php?action=invoices') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Billing").className = "dropdown open";
    }

else if (window.location.href.indexOf('clientarea.php?action=quotes') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Billing").className = "dropdown open";
    }

else if (window.location.href.indexOf('clientarea.php') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Billing").className = "dropdown open";
    }

else if (window.location.href.indexOf('account/paymentmethods') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Billing").className = "dropdown open";
    }

else if (window.location.href.indexOf('account/paymentmethods') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Billing").className = "dropdown open";
    }

else if (window.location.href.indexOf('clientarea.php?action=addfunds') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Billing").className = "dropdown open";
    }

// Support

else if (window.location.href.indexOf('supporttickets.php') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Support").className = "dropdown open";
    }


else if (window.location.href.indexOf('announcements') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Support").className = "dropdown open";
    }


else if (window.location.href.indexOf('knowledgebase') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Support").className = "dropdown open";
    }


else if (window.location.href.indexOf('download') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Support").className = "dropdown open";
    }


else if (window.location.href.indexOf('serverstatus.php') != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Primary_Navbar-Support").className = "dropdown open";
    }

});
```

I'm expecting every functions will detect correctly on which page I am and this way they can change the different class I'm targeting. Thanks.

Comment: You have multiple conditions which will match for certain urls, so the first matching condition will always be selected

Comment: Put `'cart.php?gid=addons'` before your `'cart.php'` test... and so on.

Comment: Is there a way for the Javascript functions to search for very specific and restricted URLs?

Comment: Have you tried changing `window.location.href.indexOf('/cart.php?a=add&amp;domain=register') != -1)`
to `window.location.href.includes('domain=register')`?